# Is "Event-based push" enabled in Artifactory Pro?

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory Professional 5.9.0 rev 50900900

Regarding to documentation Artifactory Pro supports "Event-based push"

I am create 2 test repos with replication from one to second and "Enable Event Replication" enabled

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOJdw.jpg)

But then I upload artifact I see it in second repo only after 5 min (when cron replication runs). No imediately event replication. And no replication events in log except cron events.

Comment: what type of license do you have: pro or enterprise?

Comment: > Artifactory Professional 5.9.0 rev 50900900

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Event-based push replication is not enabled immediately after you enter license key. After a week it start to work. May be reboot needed after license key was input.

Comment: Artifactory Pro support 'Event push replication'
It is possible that you are trying to do "Multi push replication" which means., push one --> many instances and this is an Enterprise feature.

Comment: Please look on screenshot. As I say previousely "I am create 2 test repos with replication from one to second and "Enable Event Replication" enabled". So it is not multi push in any case. I have only 2 repos sender and receiver. In documentation is written what it supported. But as you see on screenshot it is a lie. Additionally official jfrog answer mailed to me 
> "event-based push replication" is only available as part of the Artifactory Enterprise Edition"

Comment: Event base is a pro feature and should work on your pro subscription. I can see from your post and replies that you are irritated, however, this is the place to seek for help, place your question and the community will assist. Share the logs and the procedures you are doing and you will get reply.

Comment: Ok. You say what answers received from jfrog salae manager "event-based push replication" is only available as part of the Artifactory Enterprise Edition" is not right and this functionality must to work in Artifactory Pro. How can I solve my problem? event-based push replication still not work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to assist you with the issue you are experiencing, please share the repository replication configuration (mask the URL and the user/pass).
In addition to that add the below to your '$artifactory_home/etc/logback.xml' at the end of the file, just above '':

```
<appender name="repli" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${artifactory.home}/logs/replication.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${artifactory.home}/logs/replication.%i.log</FileNamePattern>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>9</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>25MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="org.jfrog.common.logging.logback.layout.BackTracePatternLayout">
                <pattern>%date [%thread] [%-5p] \(%-20c{3}:%L\) - %m%n</pattern>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

<logger name="org.artifactory.addon.replication" additivity="false" >
        <level value="trace" />
<appender-ref ref="repli" />
```

This will create a new log file ($artifactory_home/logs/replication.log) that will hold the replication operations. 
Once doing so, try to deploy a file to the repository with the event replication. 
After you have the log written, please share the data from the log file

Comment: Just to clarify, this is an Event "Push" replication. (Local to local). 
Event "Pull" replication is an enterprise feature. (Remote to Local)